# Change <p-dropdown> value in protrator

Tags: protractor, primeng

I am new to protractor, I wish to change the value in my dropdown.  But my dropdown is implemented using p-dropdown of primeNG.  Current implementation in changing dropdown values is done in a plain select - option menu.

Here is my code for the

```
         <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-12 ui-lg-2" *ngIf="listOfName" style="margin-top: 10px;">    
                <p-dropdown [options]="listOfName" [(ngModel)]="marketID" [autoWidth]="true" [style]="{'width':'100%'}" filter="true" id="markers">
                    <ng-template let-name pTemplate="item">
                        <div class="ui-helper-clearfix">{{name.label}}</div>
                    </ng-template>
                </p-dropdown>
            </div>
```

Now I wish to change the value using Protractor.  How to do that?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by changing the dropdown value using protractor?

Comment: Could you post the html of the rendered DOM as opposed to the angular template?